# Import XML into Excel - Too Many Fields - How to Reduce to Just the Relevant Data

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am trying to import an XML file into Excel using a macro. I have done this before with XML files containing different types of data and they've come in fine. The problem I have is although the data is imported, it creates around 7000 different columns and takes a long time to import. Each column is a separate data type, yet the XML only has a handful of data types.

Below is the code that I'm using in VBA, which to me appears OK.

```
 strTargetFile = "C:\temp\118195_C_SSWR_1by alignment.xml"
     ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=strTargetFile, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")
```

I'm guessing the additional fields are coming from the schema in the XML? Here are the first few lines of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    -<LandXML language="English" readOnly="false" version="1.2" time="14:37:25" date="2021-03-29" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2/LandXML-1.2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2">


    -<Units>

    <Imperial directionUnit="decimal degrees" angularUnit="decimal degrees" diameterUnit="inch" pressureUnit="inchHG" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit" volumeUnit="cubicYard" linearUnit="USSurveyFoot" areaUnit="squareFoot"/>

    </Units>

    <Project name="U:\Survey\Training\2021 Training\Staking Calculations\Sample Data\XXXXXX\CAD\C3D\XXXXXX_C_STRM_1.dwg"/>

    <Application version="2021" name="Autodesk Civil 3D" timeStamp="2021-03-29T14:37:25" manufacturerURL="www.autodesk.com/civil" manufacturer="Autodesk, Inc." desc="Civil 3D"/>


    -<PipeNetworks>


    -<PipeNetwork name="STORM SEWER" desc="PROPOSED STORM SEWER PUMA STREET" alignmentRef="Alignment - PUMA STREET NW" pipeNetType="storm">


    -<Structs>


    -<Struct name="402 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Catch Basin, New" elevSump="872.89" elevRim="876.413998239272">

    <Center>177416.191751022561 443580.801445370831</Center>

    <RectStruct thickness="0.5" material="Reinforced Concrete" width="2." length="3."/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (30) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="out" elev="872.89"/>


    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>


    -<Struct name="401 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Catch Basin Manhole, New" elevSump="872.101633886739" elevRim="876.39871453188">

    <Center>177430.655495377985 443543.9480515818</Center>

    <CircStruct thickness="0.416666666667" material="Reinforced Concrete" diameter="48."/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (3) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="out" elev="872.101633886739"/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (30) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="in" elev="872.2"/>


    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>


    -<Struct name="302 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Catch Basin, New" elevSump="869.35" elevRim="873.368200031799">

    <Center>177275.841495010856 443561.688859045214</Center>

    <RectStruct thickness="0.5" material="Reinforced Concrete" width="2." length="3."/>
```

```
    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>


    -<Struct name="301 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Catch Basin Manhole, New" elevSump="868.080003224001" elevRim="873.352567030156">

    <Center>177275.59769026842 443522.099609752884</Center>

    <CircStruct thickness="0.416666666667" material="Reinforced Concrete" diameter="48."/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (3) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="in" elev="868.18"/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (4) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="out" elev="868.080003224001"/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (8) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="in" elev="868.18"/>


    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>


    -<Struct name="202 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Catch Basin, New"        elevSump="867.73" elevRim="871.253169242517">

    <Center>177060.840165846836 443563.010035849235</Center>

    <RectStruct thickness="0.5" material="Reinforced Concrete" width="2." length="3."/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (7) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="out" elev="867.73"/>


    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>


    -<Struct name="201 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Catch Basin Manhole, New" elevSump="867.262507897573" elevRim="871.237565667375">

    <Center>177060.600943323603 443523.420739520108</Center>

    <CircStruct thickness="0.416666666667" material="Reinforced Concrete" diameter="48."/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (4) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="in" elev="867.36"/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (5) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="out" elev="867.262507897573"/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (7) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="in" elev="867.36"/>


    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>


    -<Struct name="102 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Catch Basin, New" elevSump="866.915360000626" elevRim="870.087484739165">

    <Center>176827.886969953834 443564.45584364637</Center>

    <RectStruct thickness="0.5" material="Reinforced Concrete" width="2." length="3."/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (6) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="out" elev="866.915360000626"/>


    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>


    -<Struct name="101 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Catch Basin Manhole, Sump, New" elevSump="864.649698372683" elevRim="870.07365411646">

    <Center>176827.643768475857 443524.866582356801</Center>

    <CircStruct thickness="0.416666666667" material="Reinforced Concrete" diameter="48."/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (1) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="out" elev="866.649698372683"/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (5) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="in" elev="866.75"/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (6) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="in" elev="866.75"/>


    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>


    -<Struct name="100 (STORM SEWER)" desc="Storm, Flared End Section, New" elevRim="868.291666666667">

    <Center>176772.499770008988 443440.935562159808</Center>

    <OutletStruct/>

    <Invert refPipe="Pipe - (1) (STORM SEWER)" flowDir="in" elev="866.5"/>


    -<Feature source="Autodesk Civil 3D" code="StructureFeature">

    <Property value="depth" label="controlSumpBy"/>

    </Feature>

    </Struct>

    </Structs>


    -<Pipes>


    -<Pipe name="Pipe - (1) (STORM SEWER)" desc="Reinforced Concrete Pipe, New" length="100.425590004863" slope="0.001490641369" refStart="101 (STORM SEWER)" refEnd="100 (STORM SEWER)">

    <CircPipe thickness="0.25" material="RCP" diameter="24."/>

    <PipeFlow timeInlet="0." runoffCoeff="0." hglUp="0." hglDown="0." areaCatchment="0." flowIn="0."/>

    </Pipe>


    -<Pipe name="Pipe - (3) (STORM SEWER)" desc="Reinforced Concrete Pipe, New" length="156.638617678046" slope="0.025044038207" refStart="401 (STORM SEWER)" refEnd="301 (STORM SEWER)">

    <CircPipe thickness="0.1875" material="RCP" diameter="15."/>

    <PipeFlow timeInlet="0." runoffCoeff="0." hglUp="0." hglDown="0." areaCatchment="0." flowIn="0."/>

    </Pipe>


    -<Pipe name="Pipe - (4) (STORM SEWER)" desc="Reinforced Concrete Pipe, New" length="215.002011584445" slope="0.00334883965" refStart="301 (STORM SEWER)" refEnd="201 (STORM SEWER)">

    <CircPipe thickness="0.1875" material="RCP" diameter="15."/>

    <PipeFlow timeInlet="0." runoffCoeff="0." hglUp="0." hglDown="0." areaCatchment="0." flowIn="0."/>

    </Pipe>


    -<Pipe name="Pipe - (5) (STORM SEWER)" desc="Reinforced Concrete Pipe, New" length="232.962225347581" slope="0.002199966699" refStart="201 (STORM SEWER)" refEnd="101 (STORM SEWER)">

    <CircPipe thickness="0.208333333333" material="RCP" diameter="18."/>

    <PipeFlow timeInlet="0." runoffCoeff="0." hglUp="0." hglDown="0." areaCatchment="0." flowIn="0."/>

    </Pipe>


    -<Pipe name="Pipe - (6) (STORM SEWER)" desc="Reinforced Concrete Pipe, New" length="39.590353627399" slope="0.004176811468" refStart="102 (STORM SEWER)" refEnd="101 (STORM SEWER)">

    <CircPipe thickness="0.1875" material="RCP" diameter="15."/>

    <PipeFlow timeInlet="0." runoffCoeff="0." hglUp="0." hglDown="0." areaCatchment="0." flowIn="0."/>

    </Pipe>


    -<Pipe name="Pipe - (7) (STORM SEWER)" desc="Reinforced Concrete Pipe, New" length="39.591748019644" slope="0.009345789887" refStart="202 (STORM SEWER)" refEnd="201 (STORM SEWER)">

    <CircPipe thickness="0.1875" material="RCP" diameter="15."/>

    <PipeFlow timeInlet="0." runoffCoeff="0." hglUp="0." hglDown="0." areaCatchment="0." flowIn="0."/>

    </Pipe>


    -<Pipe name="Pipe - (8) (STORM SEWER)" desc="Reinforced Concrete Pipe, New" length="39.607284687071" slope="0.029552917401" refStart="302 (STORM SEWER)" refEnd="301 (STORM SEWER)">

    <CircPipe thickness="0.1875" material="RCP" diameter="15."/>

    <PipeFlow timeInlet="0." runoffCoeff="0." hglUp="0." hglDown="0." areaCatchment="0." flowIn="0."/>

    </Pipe>


    -<Pipe name="Pipe - (30) (STORM SEWER)" desc="Reinforced Concrete Pipe, New" length="39.596068422868" slope="0.017428618942" refStart="402 (STORM SEWER)" refEnd="401 (STORM SEWER)">

    <CircPipe thickness="0.1875" material="RCP" diameter="15."/>

    <PipeFlow timeInlet="0." runoffCoeff="0." hglUp="0." hglDown="0." areaCatchment="0." flowIn="0."/>

    </Pipe>

    </Pipes>

    </PipeNetwork>

    </PipeNetworks>

    </LandXML>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Difficult to say based on what you've posted.  Are you able to share the full XML file?

Comment: Remember XML is an open-ended, nested design type that may or may not map cleanly into the 2D structure of spreadsheets (rows by columns). No two XMLs are necessarily the same structure. Therefore, you need a customized solution for appropriate import to spreadsheet.

Comment: I added the full XML to the post.

I will note that the data from the XML does come in, and it comes into neat columns, there are just thousands of empty columns that are the problem.